# How to document APIs that send callback requests using Postman?

Tags: postman

I'm creating a documentation for a collection that I have on Postman, and one of the requests in my collection is an asynchronous translate post request. It receives a request and responds with the `translation_id`. And then after the backend is done translating, it sends a callback request to the `callback_url` specified in the user's request params.
I'm using Postman to publish my documentation, but I'm not sure how to make the documentation clear for the reader regarding the callback method.

I can explain in the description box of the request how the request behaves and include a sample callback request, but I don't think that this is the best way.